# Does Navier-Stokes "recognize" existence of induced drag, can we get induced drag from them?

Tags: aerodynamics, theory, cfd

*"Early aerodynamic mathematical methods rely on potential flow concepts that formally isolate aerodynamic drag into a profile and an induced drag component. The more recent evolution of Navier–Stokes-based Computational Fluid Dynamics (CFD) methods typically directly computes aerodynamic forces. It does so using surface integration of pressure and viscous forces, which does not readily enable conventional separation of profile and induced drag. Isolating induced drag from aerodynamic drag is not well developed using CFD, leading to the present effort that derives a mathematical framework to extract induced drag from CFD model results."*

[source](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/5.0051080)

From text above it seems that Navier-Stokes equations dont recognize induced drag.

Does Navier-Stokes "recognize" existence of induced drag, can we get induced drag from them?

Comment: Cfd does not calculate full Navier stokes, but rather some simplification, as that still would be too computationally expensive...

Comment: "by hand" solution are definitely always needed in order to know if the solution given by the computer is actually correct. Even the writer of the paper you linked used the "by hand" solution to proof its simulation. Finally, also the most complex CFD calculates induced drag just like Prandtl did: solving the equation in the Treffz plane. Why? Because this is how induced drag is defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NS CFD will 'Recognize' induced drag in the sense that it can calculate it accurately (when done right).

However, NS CFD will not separate induced drag out from other sources of drag -- including profile, wave, trim, interference, cooling, etc.

NS CFD estimates the shear stress and pressure on every small area of surface on a body (typically triangles or quads).  To get forces and moments, those shear stress and pressures are multiplied by the local face area and summed.  In the end, the NS code can report the total force and also the force from the sum of shear stresses and the force from the sum of pressures.

Each of these forces is a vector, so they can be resolved into X,Y,Z components or into Lift, Drag, and Sideforce components (similar with the moments).

So, we can consider that a NS code will report

CD=CDp+CDs -- Total drag coefficient is the sum of the pressure and shear contributions.

Traditional CFD force summation can not break those terms apart.  It can't tell where they came from.

Classical aerodynamic theory can decompose these terms further -- usually because we came at it the other way.  We started with simplifications that could only calculate one source of drag or another.  With enough models (each with different simplifications), we can add all the sources together to get an approximation of the total.

Pressure drag has sources from:
induced drag
form / parasite / profile drag
flow separation
wave drag

The above paper is mostly concerned with isolating the induced and form drag contributions of pressure drag for an aircraft without separation and without wave drag.

Comment: If cfd can't separate induced drag how then it calculate correctly?

Comment: If induced drag is pressure drag why is hard to extract it( the more so NS separate shear from pressure)?

Comment: CFD solves the conservation of mass, momentum, and energy for a discretized domain around a body.  This results in the pressures and shears -- but not a determination of their causation.

Recall that even a viscous boundary layer around a 2D airfoil causes a pressure drag.  This is part of form drag or profile drag.

CFD can't tell what pressure is due to form drag vs. induced drag.  It is just pressure to it.

Comment: but if cfd substract pressure drag at zero lift from pressure  drag when wing produce lift, then it can get induced drag? Isnt this simple operation for cfd?

Comment: No, the viscous pressure drag actually varies with lift.  Notice 2D drag data looks like a parabola -- even though there is no induced drag in 2D.  Further complicating things, aircraft are complex shapes whose wings are often twisted -- the zero-lift condition for an aircraft is not likely zero-lift everywhere.

Comment: what is viscous pressure drag?

Comment: It is a part of profile drag and form drag.  When a boundary layer leaves the trailing edge of an airfoil, it has finite thickness.  The displacement thickness is the amount that the inviscid streamline would be displaced from the body -- creating an equivalent inviscid airfoil shape.  The pressure integral around this equivalent airfoil is zero.  However, you are also now cutting across the finite thickness of the boundary layer at the trailing edge.  That surface has a base dragon it that amounts to the viscous pressure drag.  It is a pressure drag that would not exist in inviscid flow.